# How to detach the JProfiler GUI remote server

Tags: jprofiler

I tried to Profile remote server JVM using JProfiler.The first time I can connect JProfiler. After closing the connection again tried to connect through JProfiler. Error message show JProfiler GUI connected. How can I resolve this issue?

1. Process show highlighted red color.

[image]

2. Then try to open it shows below error message.

[image]

Comment: This means that the connection was terminated in a non-regular way. If you detach normally, it will show up with a green background and you will be able to attach again. In this case the agent is in a non-defined state that does not allow another attach.

Comment: yes @IngoKegel, that connection was terminated non-regular way. I renamed a session name and after I closed the JProfiler window. Again I delete that session and create a new session above error message popup.

Comment: Creating a new session will not help in that case, only restarting the profiled JVM.